# React native relative image path loading

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to use some images in my react-native project.

My project has the following structure:

```
./index.android.js

./images/icon.png
```

I am trying to load the image within a view within index.android.js:

```
<View>
        <Image
          source={require('./images/icon.png')}
          style={styles.icon}
        />
</View>
```

I know that the images are found, because I am not getting any errors (if I try to require a non-existing image I do). But nevertheless the images are not loaded and it's an empty box where the image should be.

What am I doing wrong? I am using react-native 0.15.0, using a mobile device for testing.

Update:

So I found this within my build.gradle file for my app:

```
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
```

My images are not in that folder. I suppose that's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running Windows?  I ran into this exact same issue and it turned out to be a bug in `packager/react-packager/src/Bundler/index.js` with how the asset URL path is being generated.  It's using the `path` module to convert the local file path to a URL path but the `path` module returns paths with native path separators.  On Windows, you end up with invalid URL paths due to the paths having backslashes rather than slashes.  A quick fix for this is to replace backslashes with slashes.

See the file diff in my pull request for details.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/4416/files

**Update:** My pull request has been accepted and released with version 0.17.

Comment: I am using windows. I've manually added your pieces of code into mine, because the file I have seems to be different (though I'm pretty sure I have the latest version of react-native) and my node server wouldn't start if I copied the whole thing. My images are loading fine now. If I understand correctly the pull request was rejected because of somethingsomething? (Just asking because I would really like to see this fixed)

Comment: @Nirri The pull request is still open.  It failed an automated test but that test is completely unrelated to my change and was failing on other recent pull requests.  Hopefully that doesn't hold things up but I'll keep an eye on it to see if I can keep it going.  If you feel like it, I'd suggest adding a comment to my pull request confirming that you had the same issue so they know it wasn't just me having the issue.

Comment: I see. I left a comment. Thank you for your help.