# Where to store images in react native for Android and iOS?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and want to build a small test app in Android and iOS.

I have created an images directory alongside my index.ios.js and index.android.js files.

My code below produces a red screen error saying "unable to resolve module ./images/tree.png... Invalid directory...":

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
} = React;

var TestApp = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>test app</Text>
        <Image 
          style={styles.thumbnail}
          source={require('./images/tree.png')} /> />
      </View>
    );
  },
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  thumbnail: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestApp', () => TestApp);
```

Where should I place my images and how should I reference them?

Comment: According to [React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) `The image name is resolved the same way JS modules are resolved. In the example above the packager will look for my-icon.png in the same folder as the component that requires it.`

Without knowing your folder structure it sounds like your folder is in the same place as your js file. Did you read upgrade from a previous RN version? There's some build system hooks that maybe could help.

Comment: Upgrading my RN version did the trick. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks correct assuming that the `images` directory is in the same location as the `index.*.js` files.

What version of React Native do you have?  From the [Images](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) doc page:

> Available React Native 0.14+. If you've generated your project with
>   0.13 or earlier, read this. The new asset system relies on build hooks for Xcode and Gradle that are included in new projects generated with
>   react-native init. If you generated your projects before that, you'll
>   have to manually add them to your projects to use the new images asset
>   system. See [Upgrading](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html) for instructions on how to do this.

If you want to verify your react-native version, the easy way to do this is to run the following `npm` command from your project directory:

```
npm ls react-native
```

The current release version is 0.15.0.

Make sure you don't forget to run `react-native upgrade` after updating the package as this is required for adding build hooks for the new asset system to existing projects.  If you previously updated your react-native version without doing this, that may explain the issue you are having.

If you happen to be using Windows for development, see my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982426/react-native-relative-image-path-loading/33990026#33990026) for details on how to work around a bug with the new asset system on Windows.

Comment: Looks like it was just a case of updating my version. Yes, the images directory is in the same location as the index.*.js files. Thank you!