# Where to put images in a react-native project?

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react-native project and we are putting images currently in `/images/` folder. Is it a good path for them ? Is there any best practice?

[image]

Comment: This may help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004319/where-to-store-images-in-react-native-for-android-and-ios

Comment: You can follow this How to structure your project and manage static resources in React Native

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can add image folder to src(src/image/index.js). Image folder add index.js file create and add whole app image.
In index.js file set

```
export const IMAGENAME = require('./icon.png');
```

When import image folder

```
import { IMAGENAME } from '../image';
```

Use image:

```
<Image source={ IMAGENAME } />
```

You can add image to image folder and set path to index file.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Is there some impact on performance whether you require the image in the file you use it or whether you require globally via such a `src/image/index.js` file?

Answer (score 14):

To add a static image to your app, place it somewhere in your source code tree and reference it like this:

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```

please see the below link for more explanation:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/images

Comment: Hi Aneesh, he is asking which is the good path to put the images?. You just say 'put it any where'. For any programming there is a specific approach that includes , where to put resources, css, js files etc. It affects the execution time of the application.

Comment: @Sulu.MeanStack Yes Mr.Sulu the best way  is to put the same files in to a directory, so that it can access very easily. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 10):

In image assets folder, create index.js file and put following:

```
    const images = {
        main_bg: require('./background.png'),
        main_logo: require('./auth/home_title.png'),
        ///you can add more many images like this here.
    };


module.exports = images;
```

When using the images, you can do like this:

import  Images from '../../assets/index';
...

Comment: I'm getting an unable to resolve module error in Expo. What is the folder structure you are using?

Comment: I was doing import { images} from './images'. For whatever reason, in this context, you can not surround it with brackets.

Comment: Hi cngodles, I do not like Expo project boilerplate, because it was inconvenient to use pure node modules like crypto.js, so I used to create project with react-native-cli.
BTW, If you have module error for the images, then create and add package.json in the assets folder, and edit with only one sentence ` { "name": "@assets"}`.
Then import like this ` import Images from '@assets'`
And folder structure is nothing special. I do not think Expo project folder structure is a problem. refer my folder structure from attached screen.
[link] http://prntscr.com/jwz2l1

Comment: @cngodles exporting like `export const images`(named export) and then importing in destructured form would be convinient.

Comment: tried this solution and it did worked for me. Thnx @lingjin.w 
I'm using react native 0.71 version.

Answer (score 3):

[image]first create file "ImagesAssets.js"  in folder **assets**.

```
export const ImagesAssets = {
        bannerList1: require('./silver.png'),
        bannerList2: require('./gold.png'),
        bannerList3: require('./dimound.png'),
        bannerList4: require('./busniss.png'),
        ///you can add more many images like this here.
    };
```

then import the object to "any page" and use it.

```
import{ ImagesAssets } from '../assets/ImagesAssets';

   <View style={styles.itemsContiner}>

        <View style={styles.item}>
        <Image style={styles.imgBanner} source={ImagesAssets.bannerList1}/>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.item}>
        <Image style={styles.imgBanner} source={ImagesAssets.bannerList2} />
        </View>
      
      </View>
```