# How to add images? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, text

I tried several codes but I only have errors every time.
How to add images from my gallery (no links) one below the other, with text
*at the top and bottom* of each image?

Like this:

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/47/4/1542894301-carteeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.png))</sub>

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, ImageBackground,ScrollView } from "react-native";
import withBackground from "../components/WithBackground";

class LinksScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    
<ScrollView> 
<text>Hi</text>
 <Image source={require('./assets/images/ici.jpg')} />
 <text> Hello</text>

<text> Hi2</text>
 <Image source={require('./assets/images/ici2.jpg')} />
<text> Hello2</text>
</ScrollView> 
    
  );
  }}

export default withBackground(LinksScreen);
```

I am novice,
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the errors you are getting?

Comment: I don't have a code error but the screen of my android is red. (error code: 500) followed by a long text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to put images in a react-native project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887193/where-to-put-images-in-a-react-native-project)

Comment: @Lylys Well, can you post a screenshot of the error instead?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a screenshot of the result you are expecting?
There is something called a `FlatList` you can use that to achieve a list of images.

Note : menuData is an array of objects and Item is an object that has image title and URL

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.menuData}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return(
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Image source={require(item.imageURL)} />
                <Text>{item.imageText}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.title }
/>
```

Use this style for Text:

```
textStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',    
    alignSelf: 'center',   
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.3)', 
    height: '100%',
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Lylys i saw you error screenshot. It is related to the `export default` code that you have written. You can export only one component by default in a module. So kindly change your code to `export withBackGround(LinksScreen);` instead of `export default withBackGround(LinksScreen);`

Comment: yes I understand, but doing this 'export withBackGround (LinksScreen);' the word "export" is underlined in red. An idea to keep my background and add images? (This background code allows me to use a single code for the background of all my pages)

Comment: You are importing `withBackground` in `LinksScreen` Component. You are again trying to `export` it in the same component. So literally you are exporting it twice. Both in `LinksScreen` and in `WithBackground.js`. You are not allowed to do that is the error. So what are you trying to achieve? retain same image for all or retain the layout and load images>

Comment: What is the best solution for me?
I would like a single code that allows me to load the same background on all my tabs, but I also need to add elements to my pages (such as images, buttons .. like what I'm trying to do now .) this is not compatible with another method?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to show you a possibility of working with `native-base`, but it's just a suggestion. You can see some possibilities in the official docs: https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Components

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, ImageBackground, View } from 'react-native';
import { Card, CardItem, Text, Left, Right } from 'native-base';
import styles from './styles';

class ProductImage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ImageBackground
          style={ styles.image }
          source={{ uri: this.props.photo }} 
        >
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductImage
```

So if you want to put a photo without `props`, it's just put the link image, like `'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg'`. Don't forget to install the dependence: `npm install native-base --save`

Comment: I already have a background image => "export default with Background (LinksScreen);" 
I only want to put an image a bit like a map with text below and above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this once:

```
<ScrollView> 
  <View>
    <Text>Hi</Text>
    <Image source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')} style={{ width: '100%', 
      height: 150, marginBottom: 10, padding: 10 }} resizeMode="cover" />
  </View>
  <View>
    <Text> Hi2</Text>
    <Image source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')} style={{ width: '100%', 
      height: 150, marginBottom: 10, padding: 10 }} resizeMode="cover" />
    <Text> Hello2</Text>
   </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: As you explained above,Text between the images. I haven't added at the top of image. Do you need to add the text at top of  image?

Comment: yes but, it doesn't work the screen of my android device is still red.

Comment: I was checking here, 
You can check this:
https://snack.expo.io/@supi/YW54aW

If still you are getting any error, then just let me know. Will check from my end

Comment: this is the result : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/47/4/1542896677-46524157-297151254463668-7339745740429721600-n.jpg

Comment: Just use 

    ```   export default LinksScreen; ```

instead of 

    export default withBackground(LinksScreen);

Comment: no i need to do this to have the same background everywhere without having to copy paste the code for the background on all my tabs